# Jquery ui 1.8.10 range slider is not working with jquery 3.4.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Range slider is displaying on page(I have multiple range sliders on same page) but when I click on Range slider it display error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined
>       at b..._mouseCapture (jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js:71)
>       at b..._mouseDown (jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js:46)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js:45)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:4)
>       at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:4)

I'm not sure how to fix this issue because I used latest jQuery UI 1.12.4 version but in that case slider were disappeared.
Any suggestion what should I do?

Slider code:

````
var findSlider = $('.face_links[data-ref='+this.context.tab_id+'] '+slider.id);

$('.slider-general').slider({
                range: true,
                min: optMin,
                max: optMax,
                step: valueStep,
                values: [ curMin, curMax ],
                slidingInProgress: false,
                create: function(event, ui) {
                        var minColor = $(this).slider( "values", 0 );
                        var maxColor = $(this).slider( "values", 1 )+1;
                        findSlider.find('.pourcent-visu ul li p').slice(minColor, maxColor).css('background', '#298fee');           
                },
                slide: function( event, ui ) { // Interaction
                        slidingInProgress = true;
                        if($.inArray('#'+slider.face, ctrl.locked) == -1){
                            ctrl.locked.push('#'+slider.face);
                        }

                        findSlider.find( ".amount_range" ).val( "De " + mapping[ui.values[ 0 ]] + " à " + mapping[ui.values[ 1 ]] );
                        findSlider.find('.new-min-val').val(mapping[ui.values[ 0 ]]);
                        findSlider.find('.new-max-val').val(mapping[ui.values[ 1 ]]);
                        var elemGraphP = findSlider.find('.pourcent-visu ul li p'); 
                        var minColor = ui.values[ 0 ];
                        var maxColor = ui.values[ 1 ]+1;
                        elemGraphP.slice(minColor, maxColor).css('background', '#298fee');
                        elemGraphP.slice(maxColor, totalSteps+1).css('background', '#b2b2b2');
                        elemGraphP.slice(0, minColor ).css('background', '#b2b2b2');
                },
                change: function( event, ui ) {
                    slidingInProgress = false;
                    $('body').addClass('fav-click');
                    if($.inArray('#'+slider.face, ctrl.locked) != -1 && this.lastSliderChanged == '#'+slider.face){ // dans le cas d'un doucle changement sur le même slider'
                        ctrl.locked.push('#'+slider.face);
                    }
                    this.lastSliderChanged = '#'+slider.face;
                    //update_range(slider.face, ui.values[0], ui.values[1], mapping);

                    findSlider.find('.btn-ok-slide').fadeIn();

                    if(nSetIntervalIdentifier) clearInterval(nSetIntervalIdentifier);
                    var sliderLoop = nSetIntervalIdentifier = setInterval(function() {
                        clearInterval(sliderLoop);
                        if(slidingInProgress == false){
                            //bRunning = true;
                            //compteur_random();
                            findSlider.find('.btn-ok-slide').hide();
                            findSlider.parent().find('.select-load').removeClass('select-off');

                            if( !findSlider.parent().find('.clear-filters').hasClass('hidden') )
                            {
                                findSlider.parent().find('.select-load').addClass('loader_position');
                                findSlider.parent().find(".clear-filters").hide();
                            }

                            update_range(slider.face, ui.values[0], ui.values[1], mapping);
                        }
                    }, 2000);

                }
        });```


Here is jQuery ui code:

```/*
 * jQuery UI Slider 1.8.10
 *
 * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider
 *
 * Depends:
 *  jquery.ui.core.js
 *  jquery.ui.mouse.js
 *  jquery.ui.widget.js
 */
(function(d){d.widget("ui.slider",d.ui.mouse,{widgetEventPrefix:"slide",options:{animate:false,distance:0,max:100,min:0,orientation:"horizontal",range:false,step:1,value:0,values:null},_create:function(){var b=this,a=this.options;this._mouseSliding=this._keySliding=false;this._animateOff=true;this._handleIndex=null;this._detectOrientation();this._mouseInit();this.element.addClass("ui-slider ui-slider-"+this.orientation+" ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all");a.disabled&&this.element.addClass("ui-slider-disabled ui-disabled");
this.range=d([]);if(a.range){if(a.range===true){this.range=d("<div></div>");if(!a.values)a.values=[this._valueMin(),this._valueMin()];if(a.values.length&&a.values.length!==2)a.values=[a.values[0],a.values[0]]}else this.range=d("<div></div>");this.range.appendTo(this.element).addClass("ui-slider-range");if(a.range==="min"||a.range==="max")this.range.addClass("ui-slider-range-"+a.range);this.range.addClass("ui-widget-header")}d(".ui-slider-handle",this.element).length===0&&d("<a href='#'></a>").appendTo(this.element).addClass("ui-slider-handle");
if(a.values&&a.values.length)for(;d(".ui-slider-handle",this.element).length<a.values.length;)d("<a href='#'></a>").appendTo(this.element).addClass("ui-slider-handle");this.handles=d(".ui-slider-handle",this.element).addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all");this.handle=this.handles.eq(0);this.handles.add(this.range).filter("a").click(function(c){c.preventDefault()}).hover(function(){a.disabled||d(this).addClass("ui-state-hover")},function(){d(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover")}).focus(function(){if(a.disabled)d(this).blur();
else{d(".ui-slider .ui-state-focus").removeClass("ui-state-focus");d(this).addClass("ui-state-focus")}}).blur(function(){d(this).removeClass("ui-state-focus")});this.handles.each(function(c){d(this).data("index.ui-slider-handle",c)});this.handles.keydown(function(c){var e=true,f=d(this).data("index.ui-slider-handle"),h,g,i;if(!b.options.disabled){switch(c.keyCode){case d.ui.keyCode.HOME:case d.ui.keyCode.END:case d.ui.keyCode.PAGE_UP:case d.ui.keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:case d.ui.keyCode.UP:case d.ui.keyCode.RIGHT:case d.ui.keyCode.DOWN:case d.ui.keyCode.LEFT:e=
false;if(!b._keySliding){b._keySliding=true;d(this).addClass("ui-state-active");h=b._start(c,f);if(h===false)return}break}i=b.options.step;h=b.options.values&&b.options.values.length?(g=b.values(f)):(g=b.value());switch(c.keyCode){case d.ui.keyCode.HOME:g=b._valueMin();break;case d.ui.keyCode.END:g=b._valueMax();break;case d.ui.keyCode.PAGE_UP:g=b._trimAlignValue(h+(b._valueMax()-b._valueMin())/5);break;case d.ui.keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:g=b._trimAlignValue(h-(b._valueMax()-b._valueMin())/5);break;case d.ui.keyCode.UP:case d.ui.keyCode.RIGHT:if(h===
b._valueMax())return;g=b._trimAlignValue(h+i);break;case d.ui.keyCode.DOWN:case d.ui.keyCode.LEFT:if(h===b._valueMin())return;g=b._trimAlignValue(h-i);break}b._slide(c,f,g);return e}}).keyup(function(c){var e=d(this).data("index.ui-slider-handle");if(b._keySliding){b._keySliding=false;b._stop(c,e);b._change(c,e);d(this).removeClass("ui-state-active")}});this._refreshValue();this._animateOff=false},destroy:function(){this.handles.remove();this.range.remove();this.element.removeClass("ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-slider-vertical ui-slider-disabled ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all").removeData("slider").unbind(".slider");
this._mouseDestroy();return this},_mouseCapture:function(b){var a=this.options,c,e,f,h,g;if(a.disabled)return false;this.elementSize={width:this.element.outerWidth(),height:this.element.outerHeight()};this.elementOffset=this.element.offset();c=this._normValueFromMouse({x:b.pageX,y:b.pageY});e=this._valueMax()-this._valueMin()+1;h=this;this.handles.each(function(i){var j=Math.abs(c-h.values(i));if(e>j){e=j;f=d(this);g=i}});if(a.range===true&&this.values(1)===a.min){g+=1;f=d(this.handles[g])}if(this._start(b,
g)===false)return false;this._mouseSliding=true;h._handleIndex=g;f.addClass("ui-state-active").focus();a=f.offset();this._clickOffset=!d(b.target).parents().andSelf().is(".ui-slider-handle")?{left:0,top:0}:{left:b.pageX-a.left-f.width()/2,top:b.pageY-a.top-f.height()/2-(parseInt(f.css("borderTopWidth"),10)||0)-(parseInt(f.css("borderBottomWidth"),10)||0)+(parseInt(f.css("marginTop"),10)||0)};this.handles.hasClass("ui-state-hover")||this._slide(b,g,c);return this._animateOff=true},_mouseStart:function(){return true},
_mouseDrag:function(b){var a=this._normValueFromMouse({x:b.pageX,y:b.pageY});this._slide(b,this._handleIndex,a);return false},_mouseStop:function(b){this.handles.removeClass("ui-state-active");this._mouseSliding=false;this._stop(b,this._handleIndex);this._change(b,this._handleIndex);this._clickOffset=this._handleIndex=null;return this._animateOff=false},_detectOrientation:function(){this.orientation=this.options.orientation==="vertical"?"vertical":"horizontal"},_normValueFromMouse:function(b){var a;
if(this.orientation==="horizontal"){a=this.elementSize.width;b=b.x-this.elementOffset.left-(this._clickOffset?this._clickOffset.left:0)}else{a=this.elementSize.height;b=b.y-this.elementOffset.top-(this._clickOffset?this._clickOffset.top:0)}a=b/a;if(a>1)a=1;if(a<0)a=0;if(this.orientation==="vertical")a=1-a;b=this._valueMax()-this._valueMin();return this._trimAlignValue(this._valueMin()+a*b)},_start:function(b,a){var c={handle:this.handles[a],value:this.value()};if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){c.value=
this.values(a);c.values=this.values()}return this._trigger("start",b,c)},_slide:function(b,a,c){var e;if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){e=this.values(a?0:1);if(this.options.values.length===2&&this.options.range===true&&(a===0&&c>e||a===1&&c<e))c=e;if(c!==this.values(a)){e=this.values();e[a]=c;b=this._trigger("slide",b,{handle:this.handles[a],value:c,values:e});this.values(a?0:1);b!==false&&this.values(a,c,true)}}else if(c!==this.value()){b=this._trigger("slide",b,{handle:this.handles[a],
value:c});b!==false&&this.value(c)}},_stop:function(b,a){var c={handle:this.handles[a],value:this.value()};if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){c.value=this.values(a);c.values=this.values()}this._trigger("stop",b,c)},_change:function(b,a){if(!this._keySliding&&!this._mouseSliding){var c={handle:this.handles[a],value:this.value()};if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length){c.value=this.values(a);c.values=this.values()}this._trigger("change",b,c)}},value:function(b){if(arguments.length){this.options.value=
this._trimAlignValue(b);this._refreshValue();this._change(null,0)}return this._value()},values:function(b,a){var c,e,f;if(arguments.length>1){this.options.values[b]=this._trimAlignValue(a);this._refreshValue();this._change(null,b)}if(arguments.length)if(d.isArray(arguments[0])){c=this.options.values;e=arguments[0];for(f=0;f<c.length;f+=1){c[f]=this._trimAlignValue(e[f]);this._change(null,f)}this._refreshValue()}else return this.options.values&&this.options.values.length?this._values(b):this.value();
else return this._values()},_setOption:function(b,a){var c,e=0;if(d.isArray(this.options.values))e=this.options.values.length;d.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments);switch(b){case "disabled":if(a){this.handles.filter(".ui-state-focus").blur();this.handles.removeClass("ui-state-hover");this.handles.attr("disabled","disabled");this.element.addClass("ui-disabled")}else{this.handles.removeAttr("disabled");this.element.removeClass("ui-disabled")}break;case "orientation":this._detectOrientation();
this.element.removeClass("ui-slider-horizontal ui-slider-vertical").addClass("ui-slider-"+this.orientation);this._refreshValue();break;case "value":this._animateOff=true;this._refreshValue();this._change(null,0);this._animateOff=false;break;case "values":this._animateOff=true;this._refreshValue();for(c=0;c<e;c+=1)this._change(null,c);this._animateOff=false;break}},_value:function(){var b=this.options.value;return b=this._trimAlignValue(b)},_values:function(b){var a,c;if(arguments.length){a=this.options.values[b];
return a=this._trimAlignValue(a)}else{a=this.options.values.slice();for(c=0;c<a.length;c+=1)a[c]=this._trimAlignValue(a[c]);return a}},_trimAlignValue:function(b){if(b<=this._valueMin())return this._valueMin();if(b>=this._valueMax())return this._valueMax();var a=this.options.step>0?this.options.step:1,c=(b-this._valueMin())%a;alignValue=b-c;if(Math.abs(c)*2>=a)alignValue+=c>0?a:-a;return parseFloat(alignValue.toFixed(5))},_valueMin:function(){return this.options.min},_valueMax:function(){return this.options.max},
_refreshValue:function(){var b=this.options.range,a=this.options,c=this,e=!this._animateOff?a.animate:false,f,h={},g,i,j,l;if(this.options.values&&this.options.values.length)this.handles.each(function(k){f=(c.values(k)-c._valueMin())/(c._valueMax()-c._valueMin())*100;h[c.orientation==="horizontal"?"left":"bottom"]=f+"%";d(this).stop(1,1)[e?"animate":"css"](h,a.animate);if(c.options.range===true)if(c.orientation==="horizontal"){if(k===0)c.range.stop(1,1)[e?"animate":"css"]({left:f+"%"},a.animate);
if(k===1)c.range[e?"animate":"css"]({width:f-g+"%"},{queue:false,duration:a.animate})}else{if(k===0)c.range.stop(1,1)[e?"animate":"css"]({bottom:f+"%"},a.animate);if(k===1)c.range[e?"animate":"css"]({height:f-g+"%"},{queue:false,duration:a.animate})}g=f});else{i=this.value();j=this._valueMin();l=this._valueMax();f=l!==j?(i-j)/(l-j)*100:0;h[c.orientation==="horizontal"?"left":"bottom"]=f+"%";this.handle.stop(1,1)[e?"animate":"css"](h,a.animate);if(b==="min"&&this.orientation==="horizontal")this.range.stop(1,
1)[e?"animate":"css"]({width:f+"%"},a.animate);if(b==="max"&&this.orientation==="horizontal")this.range[e?"animate":"css"]({width:100-f+"%"},{queue:false,duration:a.animate});if(b==="min"&&this.orientation==="vertical")this.range.stop(1,1)[e?"animate":"css"]({height:f+"%"},a.animate);if(b==="max"&&this.orientation==="vertical")this.range[e?"animate":"css"]({height:100-f+"%"},{queue:false,duration:a.animate})}}});d.extend(d.ui.slider,{version:"1.8.10"})})(jQuery);
;
````

Comment: jQueryUI 1.8 is very old and doesn't play nicely with the latest jQuery. Update it to 1.12 at least

Comment: I have used jquery ui 1.12 and getting this error `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:4 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value'
    at Function.error (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLParagraphElement.<anonymous> (jquery-ui-1.12.4.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:4)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:4)
    at jQuery.fn.init.t.fn.<computed> [as slider] (jquery-ui-1.12.4.js:6)`

Comment: Incorrect Syntax: `$('.slider-general")`. Cannot mix `'` and `"`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading back on this question, if you're pulling from a CDN, try pulling from the latest jQuery UI version. I also got this problem, and it was solved by using a later jQuery UI version.